# Cannot attach Azure container registries to Azure kubernetes service

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

Trying to attach ACR to AKS in azure but getting

`Could not create a role assignment for ACR. Are you an Owner on this subscription?`

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Login: `az login`
2. To move servicePrincipal.json: `az ad sp create-for-rbac --skip-assignment`
3. To get the service principal object id: `az ad sp list --display-name acrrgdevfahim` and got the id from result:

```
{
  "appId": "18843c4f-b406-4f0d-9fa3-219058a0f23a",
  "displayName": "azure-cli-2023-03-12-09-56-37",
  "password": "ACQ8Q~Oh.3_R~nqlqtek0ndYeOAAzJg6njU9mbi2",
  "tenant": "8aa57581-5266-4503-a692-a10815c0a5a6"
}
fahimhoque@Arnob ~ % az ad sp list --display-name acrrgdevfahim
[
  {
    "accountEnabled": true,
    "addIns": [],
    "alternativeNames": [
      "isExplicit=False",
      "/subscriptions/45f28bb3-dd53-47e9-b42b-38a49f7a8ec4/resourcegroups/RG-dev/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/acrrgdevfahim"
    ],
    "appDescription": null,
    "appDisplayName": null,
    "appId": "6b19686e-30f0-4805-806f-c4ca9ed8bbd4",
    "appOwnerOrganizationId": null,
    "appRoleAssignmentRequired": false,
    "appRoles": [],
    "applicationTemplateId": null,
    "createdDateTime": "2023-03-12T06:54:39Z",
    "deletedDateTime": null,
    "description": null,
    "disabledByMicrosoftStatus": null,
    "displayName": "acrrgdevfahim",
    "homepage": null,
    "id": "c465e0ec-dba8-4783-bbff-ee9944a69763",
    "info": null,
    "keyCredentials": [
      {
        "customKeyIdentifier": "4E9BFDB4314ADD4B76713CE558593C75874AD534",
        "displayName": "CN=6b19686e-30f0-4805-806f-c4ca9ed8bbd4",
        "endDateTime": "2023-06-10T06:49:00Z",
        "key": null,
        "keyId": "661bb2e7-d8d1-41b8-980d-7728875554b2",
        "startDateTime": "2023-03-12T06:49:00Z",
        "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
        "usage": "Verify"
      }
    ],
    "loginUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "notes": null,
    "notificationEmailAddresses": [],
    "oauth2PermissionScopes": [],
    "passwordCredentials": [],
    "preferredSingleSignOnMode": null,
    "preferredTokenSigningKeyThumbprint": null,
    "replyUrls": [],
    "resourceSpecificApplicationPermissions": [],
    "samlSingleSignOnSettings": null,
    "servicePrincipalNames": [
      "6b19686e-30f0-4805-806f-c4ca9ed8bbd4",
      "https://identity.azure.net//ob5N0+Wkcw9erM4VGKOVJ1T/5bYaBWcqVa1x47nLZo="
    ],
    "servicePrincipalType": "ManagedIdentity",
    "signInAudience": null,
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null,
    "verifiedPublisher": {
      "addedDateTime": null,
      "displayName": null,
      "verifiedPublisherId": null
    }
  }
]
```

4. Assigning pull permission `az role assignment create --assignee-object-id c465e0ec-dba8-4783-bbff-ee9944a69763 --scope /subscriptions/45f28bb3-dd53-47e9-b42b-38a49f7a8ec4/resourceGroups/RG-dev/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/acrrgdevfahim --role acrpull`
5. Finally: `az aks update -n aksclusterfahim -g RG-dev  --attach-acr acrrgdevfahim`

which gives the result:

```
Could not create a role assignment for ACR. Are you an Owner on this subscription?
```

Now from my portal in subscriptions page I can see myself marked as owner of the subscription. How do I resolve this issue?

**Update 1:**

Upon further investigation for this two queries:

1. `az role assignment list --all --include-classic-administrators --query "[?principalName=='fhoque.arnob@outlook.com']"` Result: []
2. `az role assignment list --all --output table`

Result:

```
    Role         Scope
    ----------------------------------------------------------------  -----------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- fhoque.arnob_outlook.com#EXT#@fhoquearnoboutlook.onmicrosoft.com 
    Owner        /subscriptions/45f28bb3-dd53-47e9-b42b-38a49f7a8ec4
    a48be5d4-727b-444b-99d9-e8b03ab75c16                             
    Contributor 
    /subscriptions/45f28bb3-dd53-47e9-b42b-38a49f7a8ec4/resourceGroups/MC_RG-dev_aksclusterfahim_centralindia
    fhoque.arnob_outlook.com#EXT#@fhoquearnoboutlook.onmicrosoft.com 
    Owner       
    /subscriptions/45f28bb3-dd53-47e9-b42b-38a49f7a8ec4/resourceGroups/RG-dev
    c119ef5d-7f74-4a5d-a83d-dfae0bbbca61                             
    AcrPull     
    /subscriptions/45f28bb3-dd53-47e9-b42b-38a49f7a8ec4/resourceGroups/RG-dev/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/acrrgdevfahim
    6b19686e-30f0-4805-806f-c4ca9ed8bbd4                             
    AcrPull     
    /subscriptions/45f28bb3-dd53-47e9-b42b-38a49f7a8ec4/resourceGroups/RG-dev/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/acrrgdevfahim
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

Try to run the below cmd in windows powershell ISE to Verify that you have the necessary permissions to create role assignments using CLI like below:

```
Az login 
az role assignment list --all --include-classic-administrators --query "[?principalName=='<your-email-address>']"
```

[image]

In azure active directory -> App registration -> Try to add service principal like below:

[image]

To check existing for the service principal:

```
az role assignment list --all --assignee <service-principal-object-id>
```

[image]

Make sure to check the ***Registry ID***

***`az acr show --name <ACRName> --query id --output tsv`***

When I try to assign to grant the necessary permissions to the service principal it assign role successfully below:

```
az role assignment create --assignee <service-principal-object-id> --scope <RegistryID> --role AcrPull
```

[image]

To attach ACR to the AKS cluster make use of below command:

```
#Attach using acr-name
az aks update -n myAKSCluster -g myResourceGroup --attach-acr <acr-name>
```

[image]

To confirm in portal `Acrpull` role assignment assigned like below:

[image]

To verfiy the connectivity between the ACR and AKS, i have created one repository in the ACR and referred that image in the kubectl deployment. It is successfully pulled the image, up and running.

[image]
[image]

[image]

***Reference***:

[Integrate Azure Container Registry with Azure Kubernetes Service - Azure Kubernetes Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-container-registry-integration?tabs=azure-cli)